# Develop same app in android and iOS and window using phonegap

Tags: cordova

Am using android studio and cordova.2.3.4 folder for creating the app.I want to create the same app for IOS and window. What to do for that.Is i have to include the plugin and permissions for IOS and window.

Comment: Use the newest cordova, not that old one and red the docs at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this for create Cordova Project for Android,iOS,Windows platform.

[Cordova CLI Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/)